# ArrayList as a DataSource of DataGridView Not Showing Data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arraylist, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that has a view as it's data source (SQL Server).  No matter what I do, I cannot make that view read/write so I'm trying to work around it.  I need to make one column editable so I thought I could make an ArrayList and set that as the data source.  Now I get no data in my DGV although my ArrayList does contain 35 rows and 4 columns of data.  Here is my code:

```
// get the data from the Table adapter, put it into an ArrayList then display it in the DataGridView -- called from Load()

private void FillReportDistributionTX()
{
    DataTable dt = this.dLV_ReportDistributionTableAdapter.GetData();
    DGVlist = ConvertDTtoArray(ref dt);
    dLV_UserReportsDataGridView.DataSource = DGVlist;
    dLV_UserReportsDataGridView.Refresh();
 }

// convert to Array
public ArrayList ConvertDTtoArray(ref DataTable dt)
{
    ArrayList converted = new ArrayList(dt.Rows.Count);
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        converted.Add(row);
    }

    return converted;

}
```

This has got me totally stumped.  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set an array list which contains some `DataRow` as `DataSource` of a `DataGridView` you will see these columns:

```
RowError | RowState | Table | HasErrors
```

That's because the `DataGridView` will show browsable properties of `DataRow`.

**But why for the same rows in `DataTable` it shows columns as expected?**

It's because the `DataView` of the `DataTable` which is used for data binding, implement [`ITypedList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist(v=vs.110).aspx) interface which provides functionality to discover the schema for a bindable list, where the properties available for binding differ from the public properties of the object to bind to. In fact it returns a `PropertyDescriptorCollection` containing some property descriptors which are created based on `Columns` of `DataTable`.

Comment: By the way, `ArrayList` is a legacy type and in cases which you want to use a list of elements which all of them are of the same type, you can use `List<T>`. But `List<DataRow>` here would not help and it works like the array list. Read the second part of the answer for reason.